# MakeFile Build and Run C Files, then Run Bash Script

Tags: bash, makefile

I have 2 .c files to build. I'd like to run them together (if possible. Or can I compile here then run in bash script?), and then run a .sh file to compare their output to expected (for testing).

My MakeFile currently:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -Werror -Wvla -std=gnu11 -fsanitize=address
PFLAGS=-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
DFLAGS=-g

p1: file_1.c file_2.c file_1.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(PFLAGS) $^ -o $@

p2: p1
    bash t.sh
```

Comment: does the solution I provided works for you

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Do you mean, that you have two different source files each of which should be compiled into a separate program, then you want to run each program?  Or do you mean, you have two different source files and you want to compile both of them together to create _one_ program, then you want to run that one program?

Comment: @DianaA does this work for you

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code which will allow you to test and run a shell script along with parallel compilation.

```
.SILENT:
.PHONY:compile objs
TARGET = program.exe
CC=gcc
# INC variable contains path where your header files are available. Compiler will # search header files in this directory.
INC = ./inc
CFLAGS=-Wall -Werror -Wvla -std=gnu11 -fsanitize=address -I$(INC)
PFLAGS=-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
DFLAGS=-g
SOURCES = file_1.c file_2.c
OBJ_FILES:= $(SOURCES:.c=.o)


objs: $(OBJ_FILES)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

all: test 

# Enable parallel compilation
compile:
    make -j ${NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS} -O objs

link : compile $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ_FILES) -o $@

test: link 
    # Execute test script
    echo "Executing test script"
    bash t.sh
```

Execute the command : **make test** or **make all**

Comment: @DianaA you can give the path of the header file to the compiler flags by passing -I option with the path where your header files are there. Example: If your header files are inside inc folder then you use : `CFLAGS = -I./inc`. I will add in the answer.

Comment: @DianA  can you please check if this works for you